# I need help to hide the unselected days by using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to write an html table having various items in different days and market.`

```js
// And here below is a function that search the item in a specific day.
function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("A110");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var s=document.getElementById("mySelect");
        var mySelect=s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            if(mySelect==1){
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
            }
            else if(mySelect==2){
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
            }
            else if(mySelect==3){
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
            }
            else if(mySelect==4){
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
            }
            else if(mySelect==5){
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[5];
            }
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                }
                else {
                     tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }       
        }
    }
```

```css
body, a{
    color:#00007f;
    }
    th{
    background-color:#ffff80;
    width:15%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    }
    #tm{
    background-color:#ffff80;
    vertical-align:middle;
    }
    font{
    size:1;
    }
    #A110, #A113{
    width:100%;
    }
    p{
    background-color:#ccffcc;
    }
    #vn{
    background-color:#ccffcc;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:15%
    }
    td{
    background-color:#ffffcc;
    vertical-align:middle  
    }
    #jd{
    background-color:#cccccc; 
    vertical-align:middle;
    }
    #fr{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    vertical-align:middle;
    color:#ffffff;
    }
```

```html
<font face="Verdana">
<center>
<p>
  <br><select name="select" id="mySelect">
    <option value="">--Select day--</option>
    <option value="1">Monday</option>
    <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="4">Thursday</option>
    <option value="5">Friday</option>
    <input type="button" id="bt" value="OK" onclick="myFunction()" />
    <br><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search item..">
</p>

<table id="A110" cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1 border=1>
<th></th>
<th id="1">Monday</th>
<th id="2">Tuesday</th>
<th id="3">Wednesday</th>
<th id="4">Thursday</th>
<th id="5">Friday</th>
</tr>
<td id="tm">market_1</td>
<td><font size=1>Maize
<td><font size=1>potato
<td><font size=1>Millet
<td><font size=1>Maize
<td><font size=1>salt
</tr>
<td id="tm">market_2</td>
<td><font size=1>millet
<td><font size=1>salt
<td><font size=1>Maize
<td><font size=1>sugar
<td><font size=1>potato
</tr>
</table>
</center>`
```

Am struggling to add some code within a function that can help to hide other items from unselected days. When I search for an item in Monday, other items from other days should be hidden

Comment: The `font` and `center` elements have been deprecated for many years. Use CSS instead.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("A110");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var s=document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var mySelect=s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        if(mySelect==1){
            table.removeAttribute("class");
            table.classList.add("Monday");
        }
        else if(mySelect==2){
            table.removeAttribute("class");
            table.classList.add("Tuesday");
        }
        else if(mySelect==3){
            table.removeAttribute("class");
            table.classList.add("Wednesday");

        }
        else if(mySelect==4){
            table.removeAttribute("class");
            table.classList.add("Thursday");
        }
        else if(mySelect==5){
            table.removeAttribute("class");
            table.classList.add("Friday");
        }
        if (td) {
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            }
            else {
                 tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

```css
`

body, a{
color:#00007f;
}
th{
background-color:#ffff80;
width:15%;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
}
#tm{
background-color:#ffff80;
vertical-align:middle;
}
font{
size:1;
}
#A110, #A113{
width:100%;
}
p{
background-color:#ccffcc;
}
#vn{
background-color:#ccffcc;
vertical-align:middle;
width:15%
}
td{
background-color:#ffffcc;
vertical-align:middle  
}
#jd{
background-color:#cccccc; 
vertical-align:middle;
}
#fr{
background-color:#ffffff;
vertical-align:middle;
color:#ffffff;
}
table.Monday tr>:nth-child(n+1),
table.Tuesday tr>:nth-child(n+1),
table.Wednesday tr>:nth-child(n+1),
table.Thursday tr>:nth-child(n+1),
table.Friday tr>:nth-child(n+1){
display:none;
}
table.Monday tr>:nth-child(1),table.Monday tr>:nth-child(2),
table.Tuesday tr>:nth-child(1),table.Tuesday tr>:nth-child(3),
table.Wednesday tr>:nth-child(1),table.Wednesday tr>:nth-child(4),
table.Thursday tr>:nth-child(1),table.Thursday tr>:nth-child(5),
table.Friday tr>:nth-child(1),table.Friday tr>:nth-child(6){
display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<font face="Verdana">
<center>
<p>
  <br><select name="select" id="mySelect">
    <option value="">--Select day--</option>
    <option value="1">Monday</option>
    <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="4">Thursday</option>
    <option value="5">Friday</option>
    <input type="button" id="bt" value="OK" onclick="myFunction()" />
    <br><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search item..">
</p>

<table id="A110" cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1 border=1>
<th></th>
<th id="1">Monday</th>
<th id="2">Tuesday</th>
<th id="3">Wednesday</th>
<th id="4">Thursday</th>
<th id="5">Friday</th>
</tr>
<td id="tm">market_1</td>
<td><font size=1>Maize
<td><font size=1>potato
<td><font size=1>Millet
<td><font size=1>Maize
<td><font size=1>salt
</tr>
<td id="tm">market_2</td>
<td><font size=1>millet
<td><font size=1>salt
<td><font size=1>Maize
<td><font size=1>sugar
<td><font size=1>potato
</tr>
</table>
</center>`
```

Comment: @Mister Jojo I repeat to you. this is the code of the author of the question. based on it. let it fix bugs (which are not bugs by the way, curve validator). he just used shorter code. if you check your code, even there the validator will find errors.

Comment: so you know some developers use shorthand code. for example, do not write the closing tag in some places. and it doesn't make the code wrong.
and this is the decision of the Author of the Question. I don’t need to poke some stupid validator that is incapable of thinking, there is a piece of algorithm in the validator, so you know.
if you want, adjust to the validator. But! There are many different ways to write code. And the fact that you do not know how to shorten the code or do not want is your problem. Not mine or the author's question.

Comment: The author has an abbreviated code! Therefore, the validator throws errors.

Comment: @Mister Jojo You don't have to do the whole job for another person. This is his code. And the author doesn't care about you, me or others.